# Finding tags in a string in iOS

Tags: ios, regex, string

I don't know how I should do this, I have tried using code like:

```
NSString *stringToFind = @"Hi";
NSString *fullString = @"Hi Objective C!";
NSRange range = [fullString rangeOfString :stringToFind];
if (range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"I found something.");
}
```

But it doesn't fit my needs, I want to search for a string like `#customstring` (# means a tag) where the tag is specified by the user so they enter something like this `Something #hello #world`, what I want to do is search for all the `#` and the string attached to it and save it somewhere.

**EDIT:** The tag string created, I am saving that in a plist, but when I save it, it only saves one tag because I simply specified the string as tag. So like this:

```
[db addNewItem:label tagString:tag];
```

I need **all** of the tags created. For example in my logs:

I log `tag`, this comes up `#tag`,
I log `tag` again with two tags like this `Something #hello #world` I get two tags like this:`#hello` & `#world` each separate logs.

The result I want is this:

`#hello, #world` and then store it in a string and save it to my `DB`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a regular expression:

```
NSString *input = @"Something #hello #world";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"#\\w+" options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:input options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, input.length)];

NSLog(@"%d matches found.", matches.count);
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSString *tag = [input substringWithRange:[match range]];
    NSLog(@"%@", tag);
}
// #hello
// #world
```

---

**EDIT** To get the tags without the hash character `#`, you should use a capturing group in the regex like the following:

```
NSString *input = @"Something #hello #world";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"#(\\w+)" options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:input options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, input.length)];

NSLog(@"%d matches found.", matches.count);
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSString *tag = [input substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];
    NSLog(@"%@", tag);
}
// hello
// world
```

---

**EDIT** To get a string that contains the input string except the tags, you can use the following method:

```
NSString *stringWithoutTags = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:input options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, input.length) withTemplate:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", stringWithoutTags);
// Something
```

---

**Edit** Now that you have the different tags, you can create a string that contains them like this:

```
NSMutableArray *tagsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSString *tag = [input substringWithRange:[match range]];
    [tagsArray addObject:tag];
}
NSString *tagsString = [tagsArray componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
NSLog(@"tagsString: %@", tagsString);
```

Comment: if there any way I can get the the result string, like `hello` from the `#hello`.

Comment: One minor tweak to sch's solution: use this regex: @"#[\\p{Letter}]+". It matches all unicode letters. So it also works with non-english alphabets. Might be useful for european languages, for example.

Comment: Ravin455: Please read the NSString documentation. That is very, very basic string handling, to strip the # from the string. It's not hard. :)

Comment: Is there any way I can exclude the tags from a string?

Comment: I found an error when excluding the tag with `rangeAtIndex`, it says its out of range. I also found out that when logging the result the tag string only includes one tag, and no I didn't mean to exclude the tag string. I meant to exclude the tags out of the original input string.

Comment: @Ravin455 - Did you notice that the second version of the code (the one that uses `rangeAtIndex`) has a modified pattern: `@"#([A-Za-z]+)"`,? And do you get the error when you use it?

Comment: @Ravin455 -  I've updated my answer to show how to compute a string where the tags are excluded, If you need a different result, you should consider posting a new question because it is different from your original question.

Comment: @sch Theres another bug, which is when giving the tag string it only gives one which is the last tag you enter e.g. "Something #hello #world", world is given and hello is excluded. Do you have to change the range?

Comment: Are you sure? When I test the code I get the two tags. Don't forget that you need the for loop. Also, why *"another bug"*? What was the first one? Can you update your question with your current code that produces the two bugs?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misused the word `bug` but yeah I got the loop it's just that it creates two tag strings for each and I need to save them all in one.

Comment: Still not clear. Please update your question with the exact description of the result you want and with an example. For instance, what does *"I need to save them all in one"* mean?

Answer (score -1):

I would split it into an array separated by # and then for each one split again by space and pick the first word for each:

```
  NSArray *chunks = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @"#"];
```